# Generate a set of M elements from an array of size N

Tags: java, arrays, random, set, probability

### UPDATE: according to the comments let's make some clarifications.

I'm trying to understand solution for the following task:
Randomly generate a set of M elements from an array of size N. Each element must have equal probability of being chosen.

I found the following solution (I've already read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755472/randomly-generate-a-set-of-m-integers-from-an-array-of-size-n), but it does not answer my question):

```
int rand(Random random, int min, int max) {
  return random.nextInt(1 + max - min) + min;
}

char[] generateArray(char[] original, int subsetSize) {
  char[] subset = new char[subsetSize];
  Random random = new Random();

  for (int i = 0; i < subsetSize; i++) {
    subset[i] = original[i];
  }
  for (int i = subsetSize; i < original.length; i++) {
    int r = rand(random,0, i);
    boolean takeIthElement = r < subsetSize;
    if (takeIthElement) {
      subset[r] = original[i];
    }
  }

  return subset;
}
// rand() function returns inclusive value 
// i.e. rand(0, 5) will return from 0 to 5
```

This code was found in book "Cracking the coding interview" (Section Hard, Task 3).
Author explains it as follows:

> Suppose we have an algorithm that can pull a random set of `m` elements from an array of size `n - 1`. How can we use this algorithm to pull a random set of `m` elements from an array of size `n`? We can first pull a random set of size m from the first `n - 1` elements. Then, we just need to decide if `array[n]` should be inserted into our subset (which would require pulling out a random element from it). An easy way to do this is to pick a random number k from 0 through n. If `k < m`, then insert `array[n]` into `subset[k]`. This will both "fairly" (i.e., with proportional probability) insert `array[n]` into the subset and "fairly" remove a random element from the subset.
>   This is even cleaner to write iteratively. In this approach, we initialize an array subset to be the first `m` elements in original. Then, we iterate through the array, starting at element `m`, inserting `array[i]` into the subset at (random) position `k` whenever `k < m`.

I think author wanted to say that we need to generate **not set**, but array. So, I think the right task descriptions should be:
Randomly generate an **array** of M elements from an array of size N. Each element must have equal probability of being chosen.

If it true, than the code above does not work correctly. Reasons:

1. For example we have an array `{'1', '2', 'a', 'b'}` and `m = 2`
2. Therefore, we should have qual probabilities to generate the following sets:

`{1, 2}; {2, 1}; {1, a}; {a, 1}; {1, b}; {b, 1}; {a, 2}; {2, a}; {b, 2}; {2, b}; {a, b}; {b, a}`

My concern here is that function will never generate the following sets: 
`{2, 1}; {2, a}; {2, b}`

So, it means that it is incorrect.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174359/discussion-on-question-by-no-name-qa-generate-a-set-of-m-elements-from-an-array).

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Comment: Agree, @lexicore, only I consider it generally accepted to wait a couple of days to see if still more answers come in. Questions with an accepted answer get less attention, which may not be desired yet.

Comment: @OleV.V. Why exactly would you need yet more answers here? The question is answered in depth.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I prove it with math?

Your second `for` loop runs twice, first with `i` equal to 2, then with `i` equal to 3.

When `i` is 2, `r` becomes 0, 1 or 2, each with probability 1/3. So the char `a` is moved into your result at index 0 or 1 or not at all, each with probability 1/3. Now it is either [a, 2], [1, a] or [1, 2].

When `i` is 3, `r` is 0, 1, 2 or 3. `b` is moved to index 0 with probability 1/4, to index 1 with probability 1/4 and is not moved anywhere with probability 1/2.

In the following table I have given the result in all possible cases. The values under `r`, 0, 1 and 2, are the possible values in the first iteration (`i` = 2). To the right of `r` are the possible values in the second iteration.

```
r    0       1       2       3
0  [b, 2]  [a, b]  [a, 2]  [a, 2]
1  [b, a]  [1, b]  [1, a]  [1, a]
2  [b, 2]  [1, b]  [1, 2]  [1, 2]
```

So in the table you can read that if `r` is 0 both times, your method will return `[b, 2]`, etc.

Each of the 12 cells in the table has equal probability, that is 1/12. Let’s inspect: [1, 2], [1, a], [1, b], [a, 2] and [b, 2] are there twice each. [a, b] and [b, a] come once each, but these are the same set, so that set comes twice too. This covers all possible subsets, so they are equally likely.

Comment: `Result is, with first iteration down and second iteration across` Could you please rewrite it in other words, because I can not translate it to my mother tongue language.

Comment: @NoNameQA I have added a couple of lines of explanation instead of the phrase you quoted.

Answer (score 0):

> I think author wanted to say that we need to generate not *set*, but *array*.

No, author truly meant *set*, but happens to store the resulting *set* in an *array*. By saying that the result is a *set*, it means that the order of values don't matter, which means that `{1, 2}` and `{2, 1}` is the same *set*.

Given that, it's ok that result will never be `{2, 1}`, as long as the probability of result with values `1` and `2` is 1/6, i.e. the unordered (set) probability.

---

If you wanted an ordered result, i.e. 12 distinct results as you listed them, then the easiest solution is to shuffle the original array and take the first `M` values. That guarantees equal probability of all results and guarantees no duplicates.

Shuffling an array is usually done using a [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), which is to iterate the array and randomly swap the element with a previous element.

The algorithm in the question is a variant of that. If skips the random shuffling of the first M values, since order doesn't matter. It then randomly swaps subsequent elements with random element, except that no swap occurs if random position is > M, and value being swapped out is simply discarded, as it would end up outside result set.

So, it is a modified Fisher–Yates shuffle to generate a random sub-set in a copy of the original array, but *optimized* to skip unnecessary shuffling, given we want a set, not an ordered list/array, and that we only want a subset, not all the values.

Comment: According to the task description:
`Each element must have equal probability of being chosen.`
Does it mean that we must have equal probabilities to generate any of sets?

Comment: @NoNameQA Yes, that's what it means. If all values have equal probability of being chosen, then each distinct combination of values will have equal probability.

Comment: We should have equals probability to generate any of sets. 
Because we don't care about the elements order in the sets the following sets will be good:
`{1, 2};  {1, a};  {1, b};  {a, 2}; {b, 2};  {a, b};` or `{2, 1};  {a, 1};  {b, 1};  {2, a};  {2, b};  {b, a}`, etc.

**But** code generates: `{1, 2}; {1, a}; {a, 1}; {1, b}; {b, 1}; {a, 2};  {b, 2};  {a, b}; {b, a}`. It means we will have probability for `P({1,2}) = 1/9` and for `P({a,b}) = 2/9`. 
So it means that code is incorrect.

Comment: @NoNameQA No. Just because it only generates `{1, 2}` and not `{2, 1}`, doesn't mean that *probability* of a `1,2` pair isn't 1/6. It is. [Ole VV already confirmed this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51173120/generate-a-set-of-m-elements-from-an-array-of-size-n/51173879?noredirect=1#comment89330192_51173120) and [explained it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51173120/generate-a-set-of-m-elements-from-an-array-of-size-n/51173879?noredirect=1#comment89330854_51173120).

Comment: @NoNameQA Remember, it may return `{1,2}` 1 in 6 times, while at the same time returning `{a, b}` 1 in 12 times and `{b, a}` 1 in 12 times, i.e. the `a,b` pair is returned 2 in 12 times, aka 1 in 6 times. Since **order doesn't matter**, the result is correct, i.e. each distinct *pair* of values is returned 1 in 6 times.

Comment: Please explain me where you take 1/6 times. Code generates `{1, 2}; {1, a}; {a, 1}; {1, b}; {b, 1}; {a, 2}; {b, 2}; {a, b}; {b, a}` and it means that we see `{1,2}` 1/9 times

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174352/discussion-between-no-name-qa-and-andreas).

Comment: @NoNameQA It doesn't generate those combinations. See [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/g22RfG) where result is (approx.): `1,2` = 1/6, `1,a` = 1/6, `1,b` = 1/6, `a,2` = 1/6, `a,b` = 1/12, `b,2` = 1/6, and `b,a` = 1/12. Since `a,b` and `b,a` is the same *set*, it means `a`+`b` *pair* = 1/6 too, ergo the algorithm correctly **returned all *sets* with equal probability**.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is quite clear from the explanation and the code that the author meant set, just as they wrote. A set can be modelled as an array in the actual implementation, this does not mean anything. In programming challenges it is quite often that people use rather simple structures - like an array instead of `java.util.Set`.

So the task is basically:

> Randomly select a set of `M` elements from an array of size `N`.

Assuming `N >= M`.

Now the hard part: why does this algorithm produce the correct results?

Just looking at the algorithm, it's hard to understand how it works and why. I think this is because the algorithm is actually constructed recursively, with recursion finall unwrapped in iteration.

Let's start with the recursion.

Assume we are able to randomly select `M` elements from an array of size `N - 1`.  How do we select `M` elements from an array of size `N`?

Since there's a "new" element in the array, we can either replace one of the selected elements with it - or leave the set as it is. But we have to keep random properties.

A set of `M` elements from `N-1` can be selected in `(N-1)! / M!*(N-1 - M)!` ways.
A set of `M` elements from `N` can be selected in `N! / M!*(N - M)!` ways.

This means that we should keep the set with the `(N-M)/N` probability and replace one of the elements with `M/N` probability. We will also have to select the element to replace with `1/M` probability.

Let's see how it will look in the code. Assume `subset` is our randomly selected set of `M` elements out of `N-1`.

First we should decide if we replace one of the elements or not. We need a `(N-M)/N` probability. For this we can just generate a random number between `0` and `N`. If this number is less than `M`, we replace.

```
boolean replace = rand(random, 0, N) < M;
if (replace) {
   // then replace
}
```

Now we have to select one of the elements to replace. Since we model the array as a set, we can simply randomly select an index between `0` and `M - 1` (inclusive). So we get:

```
boolean replace = rand(random, 0, N) < M;
if (replace) {
   subset[rand(random, 0, M - 1)] = original[N];
}
```

Here we can note that if our first random value (`rand(random, 0, N)`) is less than `M`, it *is* a random value between `0` and `M-1`. Thus, we don't need the second `rand`:

```
int r = rand(random, 0, N);
boolean replace = r < M;
if (replace) {
   subset[r] = original[N];
}
```

The rest should be pretty trivial.

Base case of the recursion is `M == N`. In this case we don't replace anything so the set of selected elements is simple the original array.

After that the recursion can be simply coded as a cycle. `i` represents `N` on each step - this gives your the code your have.

Comment: `This means that we should keep the set with the (N-M)/N probability and replace one of the elements with M/N probability. We will also have to select the element to replace with 1/M probability.`
I didn't get the phrase `we should keep the set with the (N-M)/N probability` We should keep the set? Keep it in array or memeory or you mean something else?
`replace one of the elements with M/N probability` Do you mean replace one of the elements in the set?
`We will also have to select the element to replace with 1/M probability.` From where do we need to select elements? From array or set?

Comment: "I didn't get the phrase *we should keep the set with the (N-M)/N probability*" - assume we have a set of `M` element selected randomly from `N-1` elements. We need to produce a set of `M` element selected randomly from `N` elements. For this we can either just keep the current set (i.e. leave it unchanged). Or we can replace one of its elements with the "new" element. These are the options. But to get the required randomness we have to choose one or the other option with appropriate probability.

Comment: "replace one of the elements with M/N probability *Do you mean replace one of the elements in the set?*" - yes, replace one of the elements in the current (`M` of `N-1`) set.

Comment: "We will also have to select the element to replace with 1/M probability. From where do we need to select elements? From array or set?" - from the set, of course. When going from selecting from `N-1`-element array to `N`-element array we have just one additional element, so there's nothing from select from. On the contrary, in the set there are `M` elements. We have to choose one of them for replacement. That's 1/M probability.

Comment: `Base case of the recursion is M == N. In this case we don't replace anything ` why we don't replace anythinng? If so we back to my orinal question. in case of `arr = ['1','2', 'a','b']; m = 2` we will never get set `{2, 1}` and it means our probability will fail. I understand you will answer that `{1, 2} == {2,1}` are equals sets and I agree with that. BUT probability of getting `{a,b}` will not be qual to probabilit of getting `{1,2}`

Comment: "`Base case of the recursion is M == N. In this case we don't replace anything` why we don't replace anythinng?" - because if we have to randomly select `N` elements from `N` elements, we take all the elements and there's nothing left.

Comment: *If so we back to my orinal question. in case of arr = ['1','2', 'a','b']; m = 2 we will never get set {2, 1} and it means our probability will fail.* - in this case `N=4` so this is *not* the base case `N==M` we are talking about. Base case would be `arr = ['1','2']`, `m = 2`.

Comment: *BUT probability of getting `{a,b}` will not be qual to probabilit of getting `{1,2}`* - with the given algorithm, it will be. Let's start with the best case, `N=M=2`. We first select `{1, 2}` as `subset`. Next we roll the random number between `0` and `2`. If this number is `0` or `1` (probability of that is 2/3), we replace `1` or `2` with `a`. Basically with probability we get {1, a} or {a, 2} each with probability 1/3.

Comment: Next we roll the random number between `0` and `3` to decide if we replace anything with `b`. We have a chance of 1/4 to replace `1` (or `2`) with `b` in each of the cases, resulting in `{a, b}` in each case. That's 2 cases with probability of `1/3 * 1/4 = 1/12` each. This results in a `1/6` probability to get `{a, b}`. Which is an *equal* probability to all other variants.

Comment: Actually, I have shown that this algorithm produces correct probability in my answer. Please read it carefully.

Comment: Could you explain please, how did you get (calculate) `M/N` probability to insert "new" element into the set? Why not `1/M`?