# Probability of generating a set of M elements from an array of size N

Tags: java, arrays, random, set, probability

I'm trying to understand solution for the following task:
Randomly generate a set of M elements from an array of size N. Each element must have equal probability of being chosen.

I found the following solution (I've already read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755472/randomly-generate-a-set-of-m-integers-from-an-array-of-size-n), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51173120/generate-a-set-of-m-elements-from-an-array-of-size-n/), but I still have questions that are too long for comments):

```
int rand(int min, int max) { 
  return min + (int)(Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
}

int[] generateSet(int[] arr, int m, int n) {
    if (n + 1 == m) { //base case
        int[] set = new int[m];
        for (int k = 0; k < m; k++) {
            set[k] = arr[k];
        }
        return set;
    }

    int[] set = generateSet(arr, m, n - 1);
    int r = rand(0, n);
    if (r < m) set[r] = arr[n];
    return set;
}
// rand() function returns inclusive value 
// i.e. rand(0, 5) will return from 0 to 5
```

This code was found in book "Cracking the coding interview" (Section Hard, Task 3).
Author explains it as follows:

> Suppose we have an algorithm that can pull a random set of `m` elements from an array of size `n - 1`. How can we use this algorithm to pull a random set of `m` elements from an array of size `n`? We can first pull a random set of size m from the first `n - 1` elements. Then, we just need to decide if `array[n]` should be inserted into our subset (which would require pulling out a random element from it). An easy way to do this is to pick a random number k from 0 through n. If `k < m`, then insert `array[n]` into `subset[k]`. This will both "fairly" (i.e., with proportional probability) insert `array[n]` into the subset and "fairly" remove a random element from the subset.
>   This is even cleaner to write iteratively. In this approach, we initialize an array subset to be the first `m` elements in original. Then, we iterate through the array, starting at element `m`, inserting `array[i]` into the subset at (random) position `k` whenever `k < m`.

I fully understand the base case.It says that: if we have an array of size `N` and `M == N`, therefore, we should return first `M` elements from the array, because each of them will be selected with equal probability.

Than comes the hard part (recursive case) that I do not understand at all.

1. Code generates set of size `M` from array of size `N - 1`
2. Now code should decide add or not "new" element `arr[N]` to the set
3. With the probability `M / N` code decides add or not "new" element. Random works as follow:

   1. Generates random number `r` between `0` and `N`
   2. If `(r < m)` it means that `r` was generated with `M / N` probability
   3. Also if `(r < m)` it means that with probability `1 / M` we will change one of M elements in the set.

### Update:

I don't understand the following:
Imagine that we have a box with N - 1 elements. We take M elements from it. Therefore, a probability of getting set of elements will be:

`Pa(get any set with M elements using N-1 elements) = 1 / ((N-1)! / M!(N-1-M)!) = M!(N-1-M)!) / (N-1)!`

It is clear that if we will put all elements back into the box, and than take M element again, we will always create a set with equal probability.

Okay, lets imagine that we take M elements. Therefore, box now contains `N-1-M` elements.

So this is where recursive case starts:
Now we take one for new element from, lets say, our pocket. Now we should decide modify set or not.

Starting from this point I completely do not understand what to do next. My guess:

When we had N-1 elements, a probability of generating any set with M elements was:

`Pa(get any set with M elements using N-1 elements) = M!(N-1-M)!) / (N-1)!`

But we add one more new element. And now we should generate any set of M elements with probability that must be equal to `Pa`.
But now new probability will be:

`Pb = 1 / (N! / !M(N-M)!) = M!(N-M)!) / N!`

So we need to find a way to **convert** somehow `Pb` to `Pa` i.e.

`!M(N-M)!) / N!` to `!M(N-1-M)!) / (N-1)!`

And with some magic (I still do not understand how it works) recursive case do that:

1. Call R = rand(0, X) (I don't know what is X). If R equals to some Y (I don't know what Y value is), it means that we should use our new element.
2. If R equals Y, then call rand(0, M) to generate index that will be updated with new element

Question:
1. How to calculate X and Y value?

Comment: 1. It just falls out of the math. It was pretty surprising, but satisfying, the first time I worked it out.

Comment: @AndyTurner sure, but what math exactly? I tried to derive the expression, but failed tens of times.

Comment: it's been a while. I did write it up as an answer here once, but I think the question was deleted. Let me see if I can find it again.

Comment: I'm really inclined to close this question as a duplicate of:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51173120/generate-a-set-of-m-elements-from-an-array-of-size-n/
Everything is explained there.

Comment: @lexicore I'm really very confused about this algorithm and math behind it. I've read you post about 50 times and still have no idea how did you come to conclusion that if `Choose(M, N) = N! / (N-M)!` and `Choose(M, N-1) = (N-1)!/(N-1-M)! ` then we should decide to take `arr[N]` or not with `M/N` probability. I really need help. Maybe I could write you to your email?

Comment: @NoNameQA That's Bayes law.

Answer (score 1):

There are `choose(n, m) = n! / (m! (n-m)!)` ways to choose `m` elements from a set containing `n` elements. You want to choose any one of these arrangements with equal probability.

You have two choices as to whether to take a given element of not:

1. Picking "this" element, and picking the `m-1` elements from `n-1` elements;
2. or not picking "this" element, and picking the `m` elements from `n-1` elements.

You have to make the choice in a way which will yield any arrangement with equal frequency

```
P(pick) = (# arrangements which pick "this" element) / (# arrangements)
        = (# arrangements which pick "this" element) / (# arrangements which pick "this" element + # arrangements which do not pick "this" element)
        = A / (A + B)
```

introducing `A` and `B` for notational convenience.

```
A = choose(n-1, m-1) 
  = (n-1)! / (m-1)!(n-m)!

B = choose(n-1, m) 
  = (n-1)! / m!(n-m-1)!
```

Multiplying the numerator and denominator of `A` and `B` so that they have a common factor of `(n-1)! / m!(n-m)!`:

```
A = m     * (n-1)! / m!(n-m)!
B = (n-m) * (n-1)! / m!(n-m)!
```

Then:

```
P = m / (m + n - m)
  = m / n
```

As required.

Comment: By word "arrangement" you meant set?

Comment: @NoNameQA I mean a subset. I use the word arrangement because I'm thinking of the arrangement of m bits within a binary string of length n with value "1", where "1" means that a corresponding element should be picked.

Comment: One more question: Did you mean by `P(pick)`: "P(pick `this` element, and pick the `m-1` elements from `n-1` elements)"?

Comment: And one more question: Am I get it right: `A = number of subsets which will contain "new" (i.e. arr[N]) element` and `B = number of subsets which will not contain "new" (i.e. arr[N]) element`

Comment: @NoNameQA "one more question" it's the probability with which you should select choice 1.

Comment: @NoNameQA "and one more question" I'm not sure what you are asking. A and B relate directly to the terms in the previous expression.

Comment: Please take a look at my question, I've updated it with more details